Problem with Newton's method (numerical analysis)
I am not understanding how to proceed with this exercise, which asks me to solve $f(x) = 0$ by using Newton's method. It asks me to study the convergence of the sequences $x_k$ (built with Newton's method) as $x_0$ varies ($x_0 \in\mathbb{R}$).
The problem is that the given $f(x)$ are $f_1(x) = x^{2/5}$ and $f_2(x) = \vert x \vert^{1/3}$.
In these scenarios, the root is $x = 0$ but it's also the point at which the functions are not differentiable.

That is not a problem to write down the recurrence and study its convergence. You only need derivative (non-zero) at the current point of the iteration. Just don't start at $x=0$.

@Heidegger as long as the initial condition is not $x_0=0$, the sequences can be computed, you just need to see if they converge to zero.

@PierreCarre What I don't understand is that I still have to work in an interval where $f$ is not differentiable...

@Heidegger you don't need to work in any interval, you are not going to use tha usual sufficient convergence conditions for newton's method... You just need to construct this particular seuence and see what happens.

Take the example $f(x) = x^{2/5}$. If you choose some $x_0 \ne 0$, then $x_1$ is given  by
$$
x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} = -\frac 32 x_0.
$$
So, you can see that the magnitude of the sequence elements increases by $\frac 32$ each iteration. Hence, $|x_n| = |x_0| (3/2)^n$ and you can conclude that the sequence never converges to zero.
